# Whenever I import a module into my code the entire module is run

Tags: python

I'm using python to create my first independent program, It consists of two modules. I am trying to import the main module into the other one, however whenever I import the main module, it runs the entire code. I just want to use attributes and functions from this code, but I'm not quite sure how to. Any help on this matter is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Importing a module runs all code inside. Ideally this would just be variable/function definitions, but it seems you actually have code running. Of course, we can't help more without a small example of your code here.

Comment: FWIW, [this is explained in the official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts).